# Being notified on incoming call (via BLE)

Tags: raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy

I would that my python script on a raspberry get notified when my iPhone has an incoming call.
I think I need to use BLE for that, but I am unable to get some information.
Have you an idea?
Thanks

Comment: ANCS is what you would look up.

Comment: Just to add a link to the comment from @Emil https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Introduction/Introduction.html